# Random Forest using Mahout

Tags: hadoop, mahout, random-forest

I want to use Random Forest using Mahout for my work. I have started from this [tutorial](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/learning-random-forest-using-mahout). But I don't know how can I do with my own data?
Please, anyone, help me or suggest me how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

See this [tutorial](https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html). It is very helpful in my case.
you just change data description and input output path according own your data set.

data description for example.
data given below

```
ID   name   age    weight    target
1    john    18     70        Y
....
```

description will be

```
-d L C 2 N L
```

and also you can modify source code BuildForest.java or TestForest.java in mahout examples.